# How to make an infinte category of subcategory in php

Tags: php, categories

Who knows how i can make a list of categories with subcategories like as :
Categorie 1 Subcategorie1.1Subcategorie 1.1.1Subcategorie 1.1.1.1 ... .
I make somethink like this with loops of 3 while but in infinite it's a little harder i think.
while(){ while(while(){ }) } but just with 3 subcategories.

Comment: please post your code? error and ofcourse desired output?

Comment: Are we allowed to use JavaScript?

Comment: Jose's answer should get you to a point where you can post code to show what you have tried.  A recursive function is the way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your question. Not sure if next code is what you want: it adds as many subcategories as you want. Copy-paste the code in a file named **categories.php**, open your browser and run it with **localhost/categories.php** :

```
<?php
// RECURSIVE FUNCTION TO CREATE THE SUBCATEGORIES.
function display_category ( $i,$index ) {
echo "<ul>Category " . $index;
if ( $i > 1 )
//  { $index++;
    display_category( $i-1,++$index );
echo "  <li>Item</li>" .
     "</ul>";
}

session_start();
if ( ! IsSet( $_SESSION["level"] ) )
   $_SESSION["level"] = 1;

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jose Manuel Abarca Rodriguez</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
// DISPLAY THE CATEGORIES AND SUBCATEGORIES.
display_category( $_SESSION["level"],1 );
?>
    <br/>
    <br/>
<!-- FORM TO ADD SUBCATEGORY. -->
    <form action="categories.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="flag" style="display:none" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add a subcategory" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
// COUNTER IS INCREASED ONLY IF SUBMIT BUTTON ("ADD A SUBCATEGORY") WAS PRESSED.
if ( IsSet( $_POST["flag"] ) )
     $_SESSION["level"] = $_SESSION["level"] + 1;
?>
```

Comment: Hey, Bogdan, you may accept the answer or upvote it (or both!).